# When does Torna auto-save?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2, xenoblade-2-torna-golden-country

In the options menu for *Xenoblade Chronicles 2: Torna ~ The Golden Country*, there's a setting for auto-save that is disabled by default. The description says:

> When enabled, the game will save automatically at certain points.

At what points will the game save if I enable auto-save? Is there any indicator for when the game is auto-saving?

[image: auto-save option]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If auto-save is enabled, the game will save whenever you finish using a campfire. According to [HeresiarchQin on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xenoblade_Chronicles/comments/9g8554/psa_warning_checking_out_new_game_can_auto_save/), the game will also auto-save when starting a New Game or New Game+.

The saving indicator is easily missable as it's only on screen for a fraction of a second.

[image: auto-save indicator]